# Preload css background image, nivo slider issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, background, nivo-slider

I'm having some trouble getting my wrapper's background image to preload before my nivo-slider slideshow loads.  This is something my client is very picky about even though it's only a fraction of a second -_-

I've tried every jQuery and css method I've found on here and either it makes no difference or breaks the nivo-slider.

Here is a link to a test page

http://www.wheatbeakinc.com/test/

As you can see it loads fast enough for most people but like I said my client is picky about these kinds of things. Also the actual background image is larger in filesize than the test so it takes a little longer.

Can anyone offer any insight?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you insert the background image as an actual image before the slider code and set it to hidden, it should at least start loading before nivo slider. (Background images load last).

E.g.

```
<img src="your-background-image.jpg" alt="" style="display:none" />
```

If that still doesn't work, you could wrap the nivo slider in window load instead of doc ready, so it only begins after all images on the page have loaded:

```
$(window).load(function(){
  //slider code here
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that's an improvement.  I was so caught up in trying to get the background image to load first I didn't even think of making the slider load last.

Comment: Cool, yeh it's often best to use window.load for sliders anyway, since they've got images in that need to load before the slider code executes.